# Splitting a Circular Linked List in to two halves

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, circular-list

I am dealing with a problem where i am to split a Circular linked list in to two halves. If the list is even then the split would result in to two even lists. If the split is odd the first list would have the extra node.

Following is code for my node class

```
public class CLLNode {

    private int data;
    private CLLNode next;

    public CLLNode(int d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }

    public void setData(int d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setNext(CLLNode n)
    {
        this.next = n;
    }

    public CLLNode getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

}
```

Following is code for my Circular linked list class

```
public class CLinkedList {

    private CLLNode Head;

    public CLinkedList()
    {
        Head = null;
    }

    public CLLNode getHead()
    {
        return this.Head;   
    }

    public void insertFirst(int d)
    {
        CLLNode n = new CLLNode(d);
        if(Head == null)
        {
            this.Head = n;
            n.setNext(n);
        }
        else
        {
            CLLNode temp = this.Head;
            while(temp.getNext()!= this.Head)
            {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            n.setNext(this.Head);
            temp.setNext(n);
            this.Head = n;
        }
    }

    public void insertLast(int d)
    {
        CLLNode n = new CLLNode(d);
        if(Head == null)
        {
            this.Head = n;
            n.setNext(n);
        }
        else
        {
            CLLNode temp = this.Head;
            while(temp!= null)
            {
                temp = temp.getNext();
                if(temp.getNext() == this.Head)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            n.setNext(temp.getNext());
            temp.setNext(n);
        }

    }

    public void deleteFirst()
    {
        CLLNode temp = this.Head;
        CLLNode temp2 = this.Head;

        while(temp2!=null)
        {
            temp2 = temp2.getNext();
            if(temp2.getNext()== this.Head)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        temp2.setNext(temp.getNext());
        this.Head = temp.getNext();
        temp.setNext(null);
    }

    public void deleteLast()
    {
        CLLNode temp = this.Head;
        CLLNode temp2 = this.Head;

        while(temp.getNext()!= this.Head)
        {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }

        temp2.setNext(temp.getNext());
        temp = null;
    }

    public void displayList(CLLNode n)
    {
        CLLNode temp = n;
        while(temp!= null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.getData());
            temp = temp.getNext();
            if(temp == this.Head)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getLength()
    {
        int count  = 0;
        CLLNode temp = this.Head;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            count ++;
            temp = temp.getNext();
            if(temp == this.Head){
                break;
                }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public void splitList(CLLNode head, CLLNode head1, CLLNode head2)
    {
        CLLNode temp1 = head;
        CLLNode temp2 = head;
        CLLNode temp3 = head;

        while(temp2!=null)
        {
            temp1 = temp1.getNext();
            temp2 = temp2.getNext().getNext();

            if(temp2.getNext()== head)
            {
                temp2.setNext(temp1.getNext());
                head2 = temp1.getNext();
                temp1.setNext(temp3);
                head1 = temp3;
                break;
            }

            if(temp2.getNext().getNext()==head)
            {
                temp2.getNext().setNext(temp1.getNext());
                head2 = temp2;
                temp1.setNext(temp3);
                head1 = temp3;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.displayList(Head1); // This one goes in to a infinite loop..
        this.displayList(head2);

    }

}
```

Following is my main class

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        CLinkedList list = new CLinkedList();

        list.insertLast(10);
        list.insertLast(20);
        list.insertLast(30);
        list.insertLast(40);

        CLLNode head = list.getHead();

        CLLNode head1 = null;
        CLLNode head2 = null;

        list.splitList(head,head1,head2);



    }

}
```

I am able to successfully split the lists i believe but for some reason when i display the newly split list it goes in to a infinite loop. i am not sure why , if someone can please point out my mistake or suggest a fix i would appreciate it.

Comment: `temp2 = temp2.getNext().getNext();` - try this with a list of a single node. Generally, you should test this first with an empty list, then one node, then two, and so on, to iron out any wrinkles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your split operation works but there is a really simple way to split a circular list into two circular lists. Let's not worry about the even/odd stuff for now and consider what happens if you swap the next pointers of two distinct nodes in a circular list. You get two circular lists (neat, right?).

Now to split the list, first count the number of items in the list (call it n) and swap the next pointer of node at position 0 (the first node) with the next pointer of node at position n/2 (you have to follow next pointers to find this node). If the count is even, the lists are split into two lists of even length and if the count is odd, the lists are split into two lists of odd/even length respectively. So find these two nodes, swap their next pointers and assign them to head1 and head2.

You might want to handle separately the case where there is a single node or the list is empty.

Try this on a piece of paper to see that it actually works.